# Why does parseInt(string@2019) return NaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I am new to JavaScript and currently understand two things about the parseInt() method:

```
parseInt("100") // gives 100
parseInt("2019@string") // gives 2019
```

However, why would `parseInt("string@2019")` give NaN?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp: "Note: If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN."

Comment: @CodeManiac Why can't `2019@string` be parsed into any int value?

Comment: @HenryWang that was a typo i meant `string@2019`, parseInt checks for `first character` if it cannot be converted into int it will return `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the issue if you look at the [W3Schools page for `parseInt`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp):

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN.

This is why the following returns `NaN`:

```js
console.log(parseInt("O123"));
```

But if you have multiple numbers in a string, separated by a non-digit character, then it will not error - it'll just return the first number:

> Only the first number in the string is returned!

```js
console.log(parseInt("12b34"));
```

This information is also found in the [MDN page for `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `parseInt` function takes in a string as an input, and tries to convert it to a number. [Here are some examples that use `parseInt` to convert a string to a number.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parseint) Your second example `parseInt("string@2019")` returns NaN because it `string@2019` is not a valid type. Try just doing `parseInt("2019")`.

You can read more about `parseInt` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

Comment: Could you please explain why `2019@string` can't be converted into an int? I thought it was possible to parse `2019@string` since it begins with a number.

Comment: @HenryWang As explained in the comments of the original post, "Note: If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN.". 2019@string would work fine. I updated my answer to fix this.